# Getting wrong output in C program

Tags: c, io

Expected output : "total is equal to 114"

Current output : "total is equal to -334"

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>

#define SZ 3

int main(void) {
    int i, one = 0, two = 0, total = 0;

    printf(
        "Enter two whole numbers separated by a space: ");  // user enters 56 2

    total = scanf("%d %d", &two, &one);

    for (i = 0; i < SZ; i++) {
        if (i / two) {
            total = two + one / total;           
        } else {
            total -= one * two;           
        }
    }

    printf("total is equal to %d\n", total);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please explain: what should it do, which inputs, what goes wrong, etc.

Comment: What is this supposed to do?

Comment: Do you need a float result ?

Comment: i need it to answer 114

Comment: no worries I got it!

Comment: Since you have to follow only 3 iterations and *you* know what's supposed to happen after entering `52 2`, then simply print `total` as the last instruction of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

`if(i / two)` is always `false`:

- 1st iteration `->` `0 / 56 = 0`
- 2nd iteration `->` `1 / 56 = 0.02` which is treatead as `int`, so `0`
- 3rd iteration `->` `2 / 56 = 0.04` same as before

Given the above, and knowing that `0` is `false`, only the `else` block is executed 3 times, since `scanf` returns the number of read inputs, which is `2`, and you assign it to `total`, `total` begins with the value `2`, so:

`2 -= 56 * 2` is `-110`

`-110 -= 56 * 2` is `-222`

`-222 -= 56 * 2` is `-334`

And that's how you get that value.

As for the `114` value you want, it's not clear how or for what reason or logic it should be achieved.

Comment: *`1 / 56 = 0.02` wich is converted to `int` so `0`* Pedantically, there's no conversion to floating point involved - all the calculations are done directly in integer types, more like grade-school hand-calculating long division with pencil and paper that returns a quotient and a remainder - [literally](https://www.aldeid.com/wiki/X86-assembly/Instructions/div).

Comment: i like a spooky answer but I think you mean 'which' :-)